# Lucene search in sitecore with 2 websites

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

I integrated lucene search in my sitecore website which has one more website under content item in the content tree. I added a new `searchindex.config` file in `app_congif/include folder`. I've also changed the lucenesearch source to get siteroot as

```cs
SiteRoot = database.GetItem("/sitecore/content");
```

But the search isn't working. It shows:

> unable to find results item

which means it isn't getting anything in the `/Standard_Items/Search_Results`. This is my `searchindex.config`:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
   <database>
    <database id="master">
     <Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>
      <obj type="Sitecore.Data.$(database).$(database)HistoryStorage,Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param connectionStringName="$(id)"/>
        <EntryLifeTime>30.00:00:00</EntryLifeTime>
      </obj>
    </Engines.HistoryEngine.Storage>     <Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>false</Engines.HistoryEngine.SaveDotNetCallStack>
  </database>
</database>
<search>
  <configuration>
    <indexes>
      <index id="SearchIndex" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">search_index</param>
        <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer"/>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <resources type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <Database>master</Database>

            <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
            <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
               <template>{2A609D52-7B9F-49F3-83BE-047FD16397A7} </template>
              <template>{F98712D8-27DB-4324-82E6-65242F0977F9} </template>
              <template>{849CA304-3F51-4FCB-B9B3-2AC7E950B476} </template>
            <template>{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523} </template>
            <template>{52BDB3C4-0585-437C-89AD-6AAC81950633} </template>

            </include>
            <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
            <Boost>2.0</Boost>
          </resources>
        </locations>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
  </search>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

here is my content tree. I want to search in sitecore/content/DruBlue.

[image]

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Just to be sure - did you rebuild the indexes? If necessary publish your items first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in your configuration:

```
<include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
    <template>{2A609D52-7B9F-49F3-83BE-047FD16397A7} </template>
    <template>{F98712D8-27DB-4324-82E6-65242F0977F9} </template>
    <template>{849CA304-3F51-4FCB-B9B3-2AC7E950B476} </template>
    <template>{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523} </template>
    <template>{52BDB3C4-0585-437C-89AD-6AAC81950633} </template>
</include>
```

This part will only include the `{52BDB3C4-0585-437C-89AD-6AAC81950633}` template as all they have the same tag name. You need to use different tags for each of them (doesn't matter if you use `template1`, `template2` ... or `news`, `article`, `event`, e.g.:

```
<include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
    <template1>{2A609D52-7B9F-49F3-83BE-047FD16397A7}</template1>
    <template2>{F98712D8-27DB-4324-82E6-65242F0977F9}</template2>
    <article>{849CA304-3F51-4FCB-B9B3-2AC7E950B476}</article>
    <news>{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}</news>
    <event>{52BDB3C4-0585-437C-89AD-6AAC81950633}</event>
</include>
```

See [Sitecore search and indexing](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc66-usletter.pdf) pdf for more details.

Then you should rebuild the index (you can do this from **Sitecore Desktop** > **Control Panel** > **Database** > **Rebuild the Search index**. When reindexing is done try to confirm that there are any items in the index. You can use 
[Sitecore index viewer module](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Index_Viewer.aspx) or standalone [Luke - Lucene Index Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).

[Here you can find more information about solving Sitecore and Lucene problems.](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/)